# How to create a custom module in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7

I'm new to Drupal and trying to get my hands on custom modules

I have created a custom module in Drupal 7;my .info file is as follows

```
 name = Custom 
description = Custom module 
core = 7.x 
package = Own
```

and the .module file is empty..i have read somewhere that the module will show in admin/modules but it's not showing in my case..what did i do wrong?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

your info file need to be "`custom.info`" and module file will be "`custom.module`" and your module folder name also want to be "`custom`"

custom.info file

```
name = Custom
description = Custom module.
core = 7.x
package = Custom

project = "custom"
```

You can place the new module in **sites/all/modules** folder

Also try clearing cache in admin

Comment: Can you check status report at admin/reports/status and make sure all working fine.

Comment: All are working fine except one,'Upload progress' it's not enabled and needs some library file for that..although i don't think the problem is because of this...is it?

Answer (score 0):

your folder name and files name should match.Like if you name your file my.info,my.module then folder should be "my".

I just uploaded a very quick and to the point tutorial on module creation .checkout If you want:
http://www.dynamic-coders.com/how-to-create-a-custom-module-in-drupal